# How to make TextWatcher wait for some time before doing some action

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an `EditText` to filter the items in the `ListView` below it, which may contain more than 1000 items usually.  The `TextWatcher` is:

```
txt_itemSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    fillItemList();
}
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
}
});
```

The issue here is that with each letter typed by the user, the list is getting refreshed and it's this repeated list update which causes the UI to be slow.

How can I make the `TextWatcher` wait for 1-2 secs and if no more input happens after 2 secs, then filter the list. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: *Any suggestions guys?* - use the proper way of filtering the `ListView` using the adapter's `getFilter()` method.

Comment: OK, but the filtering is kind of complex. I've also got a couple of Checkboxes and other parameters to be filtered, so my only option is to get it thru SQLite query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How can I make the textWatcher wait for 1-2 secs and if no more input
>   happens after 2 secs, then filter the list.

As I already said in the comment you should look into using the `getFilter()` method of the adapter. As that may not be suitable(as you say) try to implement the same mechanism the adapter's filter uses to cancel in between filter inputs.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      mHandler.removeCallbacks(mFilterTask); 
      mHandler.postDelayed(mFilterTask, 2000);
}
```

where `filterTask` is:

```
Runnable mFilterTask = new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
          fillItemList();
     }       
}
```

Comment: when i checked LogCat now, I noticed that though the processing happens only after 2 secs, the Runnable runs many times. For eg, If I type 'sof', fillItemList runs 3 time- for 's', 'so' and 'sof'. I thought Handler.removeCallbacks would take care of it, but it didn't.

Comment: @rbH Are you sure about that? Are you typing fast enough?

Comment: Oops!. My bad. I put mFilterTask inside afterTextChanged and so each time, a new runnable was being created. Smoother than milk now :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) :

```
RxTextView.textChanges(edittext)
            .skipInitialValue()
            .debounce(TIME_TO_WAIT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe({
               //do the thing
            })
}
```