# number doesn't show in editText field when entered (Android 2.2)

Tags: android-edittext, textwatcher

I have two editText fields, with following TextWatchers in their own addTextChangedListeners. Input is read and handled correctly but the number I enter is simply not shown on the display in the second field (editText2) (even though I wait (sleep() in afterTextChanged()) a while before proceeding with setting the values of both fields to null end setting focus to the first field.

What happens is on entering a number in the first field: number is diplayed in the field and focus is moved to the second field. What happens on entering a number in the second field: cursor (blinking vertical line) is frozen, no number is shown, after two seconds: cursor is moved to first field and both fields all empty. All of this is meant to happen except that the number entered in the second field should *show* and then the system should be frozen *showing that number* for a while before setting to null and moving on to the first field.

What is wrong and how to solve?

```
public class Spel extends FragmentActivity  {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.spel);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
            int before, int count) {
        if (before==0) {  // alleen doen als editText1 leeg was
            String v = s.toString();
            if (v.equals("0") || v.equals("1") || v.equals("2") || v.equals("3") || v.equals("4") || v.equals("5") || v.equals("6") || v.equals("7") || v.equals("8") || v.equals("9")) {
                editText2.requestFocus();
                int baanWorpScore = Integer.parseInt(v);
                banenWorpScore[0] = baanWorpScore;
            } 
            else {
                // blijf wachten op goede invoer
                editText1.setText(null);
            }                       
        }

    }
});


    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        int before, int count) {
    if (before==0) {
        String v = s.toString();
        if (v.equals("0") || v.equals("1") || v.equals("2") || v.equals("3") || v.equals("4") || v.equals("5") || v.equals("6") || v.equals("7") || v.equals("8") || v.equals("9")) {
            editText1.requestFocus();
            editText1.setText(null);
            editText2.setText(null);
            int baanWorpScore = Integer.parseInt(v);
            banenWorpScore[1] = baanWorpScore;
        } 
        else {
            // blijf wachten op goede invoer
            editText2.setText(null);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found following solution, putting the delayed operations in a runnable, passed to method postDelayed of a (new) handler. This does exactly what I wished. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660636/how-to-make-textwatcher-wait-for-some-time-before-doing-some-action?rq=1) for a post that helped me find where to look for the solution.

(I actually don't know if method removeCallbacks must actually be called)

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        int before, int count) {

    Runnable mFilterTask = new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
                editText1.setText(null);
                editText2.setText(null);
                editText1.requestFocus();
         }       
    };

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    if (before==0) {
        String v = s.toString();
        if (v.equals("0") || v.equals("1") || v.equals("2") || v.equals("3") || v.equals("4") || v.equals("5") || v.equals("6") || v.equals("7") || v.equals("8") || v.equals("9")) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mFilterTask); 
            mHandler.postDelayed(mFilterTask, 2000);

            int baanWorpScore = Integer.parseInt(v);
            banenWorpScore[1] = baanWorpScore;
        } 
    }
}
```